# handleChange react-datepicker set state one step behind

Tags: reactjs

I've a datepicker that renders different tables based on the date. When I click on a date the first time it fires the handleChange on the previous date instead the new one. Basically if I click twice on a date it sends the right data.
I guess it's because of setState may be asynchronous but I still can't figure out a solution

```
this.state = {
startDate: new Date()
}

handleChange = date => {
    this.setState({
      startDate: date,
    }, () => this.getLessons())
  }


componentDidMount(){
  this.getLessons()
}

getLessons = () => {
  API calls
}

return 
<>
    <DatePicker
     selected={this.state.startDate}
     onChange={this.handleChange}
     dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
     className="border border-dark rounded text-center"
    />
</>
```

Comment: Protip, if you're not passing params, you can turn `() => this.getLessons()` into `this.getLessons`. However, instead of using the setState callback (which I've been told is no bueno at my last job), pass the date into `getLessons`. If no date is passed, default it. Then set the state there on success

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't get how can I pass date into getLessons

Comment: In your handle change method, that's where the date is.

Comment: sure, so in my handle change I'm suppose to call this.getLessons(date) AND setState(startDate: date)?

Comment: I don't see anything specifically incorrect with the code you shared and suspect there's some other logic causing your issue. [https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-smoke-fj1hu](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-smoke-fj1hu)

Comment: In your code, if I add a console.log(this.state.startDate) after the handleChange setState I get the old value. That's the behaviour I can't explain